# Where and when in the User login workflow is the last Access time timestamp set?

Tags: 8, users

I am trying to understand when exactly the last access time is set in the Drupal user login workflow.  I did notice that the following method is probably what is used to set the timestamp

```
  public function setLastLoginTime($timestamp) {
    $this->get('login')->value = $timestamp;
    return $this;
  }
```

However, I could only find the declaration but not the method call in the codebase and it has proven difficult to track it. It seems quite surprising it is not called anywhere. I am thinking that there should be a direct write to the field 'access'.

P.S The reason I am trying to get the value is to determine what all nodes are created after the user had last accessed the site.

Comment: login and access are two different fields. The former is updated on login, the latter every 180 sec when the user is accessing the site.

Comment: @4k4 – Do you know where for instance this happens? `setLastAccessTime` is only called in tests. There must be a different method then.

Comment: @leymannx, this is an event subscriber [UserRequestSubscriber::onKernelTerminate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21EventSubscriber%21UserRequestSubscriber.php/function/UserRequestSubscriber%3A%3AonKernelTerminate/9.0.x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply scan the codebase for `setLastLoginTime` and you'll see that there's actually only one single place where this function gets called. And that is [`user_login_finalize`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.0.0/core/modules/user/user.module#L435-449).

> ```
> /**
>  * Finalizes the login process and logs in a user.
>  *
>  * The function logs in the user, records a watchdog message about the new
>  * session, saves the login timestamp, calls hook_user_login(), and generates a
>  * new session.
>  *
>  * The current user is replaced with the passed in account.
>  *
>  * @param \Drupal\user\UserInterface $account
>  *   The account to log in.
>  *
>  * @see hook_user_login()
>  */
> function user_login_finalize(UserInterface $account) {
> ```

And when does `user_login_finalize` get called? Scan the codebase again. And you'll see that there are some few places only. For example in the submit handler of the user login form, in the submit handler of the user register form, or for example also in the `install_finished` handler when you after a successful interactive site installation (in the browser) get logged in as user 1.

---

Following the input from @4k4 there must be differentiated between the **last login time** and the **last access time**. Both are base fields of the user entity. The login time gets stored on every login finalize (see above) and the access time (the one you can see in the users View in the LAST ACCESS column at /admin/people) **gets renewed every 180 seconds**. This happens in an event subscriber which gets triggered on every request/response cycle – the [`UserRequestSubscriber`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.0.0/core/modules/user/src/EventSubscriber/UserRequestSubscriber.php).

The last access time then can be retrieved from [`User::getLastAccessedTime`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3AgetLastAccessedTime). I maintain a small module to calculate online, absent and offline states of a user with exactly that method: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/user_online_status/-/blob/8.x-1.0/src/StatusService.php#L83.